# Get Changeable Int From Another Form - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, int

I'm trying to finish a project for school and something doesn't work the way I want it to. I looked it up on the internet, I used those methods and it still doesn't work. Here is my code:

> > **Form 1**

```
private int selected_btns = 0;
ExampleHepler ex = null;

public int GetSelectedButtons
{
    get
    {
        return selected_btns;
    }
}

private void cheese_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((Control)sender).BackColor == Color.MediumSlateBlue)
    {
        cheese.BackColor = Color.DarkSlateBlue;
        cheese.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 2;
        selected_btns++;
    }
    else
    {
        cheese.BackColor = Color.MediumSlateBlue;
        cheese.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 1;
        selected_btns--;
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ex = new ExampleHelper(this);
}
```

> > **Form 2**

```
MainApp app = null;
public ExampleHelper(MainApp app1)
{
    app1 = app;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ExampleHelper_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    app = new MainApp();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(app.GetSelectedButtons.ToString());
}
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: is there any error? How you are showing the ExampleHelper Form

Comment: And how does it not work the way you want it to?

Comment: @UnholySheep, no, it returns only 0, every time I change that value it returns only 0

Comment: @Coding, there is not any error, it just returns 0, even if I change that value

Comment: [mcve] please - nowhere in your code are you changing the value. Also you are only reading the value on button click, that doesn't update automatically either

Comment: @UnholySheep, sorry, I edited it

Comment: @UnholySheep, how to update it, because I was thinking about that to do it with a timer but I got stuck at the update thing.

Comment: Do you mean to be assigning app1 = app, or do you mean to assign app = app1?

Comment: @Aaron, I tried both ways and none of them work

Comment: Well, the current way is wrong - regardless. You're assigning your parameter = null. You instantiate app = null, and then set app1 = app, then in load, you make app a new mainapp anyway, which would hold the default value of 0. Comment out "app = new MainApp();" in ExampleHelper_Load and I bet it throws a null reference. Change app = app1 after, and it will probably work.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks :O :D

Comment: @Aaron, by the way, I just deleted the 'app = new MainApp();' line and it worked

Comment: @DannyDSBOfficial you should still change it to app = app1 in public ExampleHelper(). And, it's also good coding practice to have "InitializeComponent();" as your first line in your constructor. I think you're probably ok in this case, but better to create good coding habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of MainApp in your ExampleHelper Form_Load event. Also, when you instantiate your ExampleHelper, you are assigning the instance variable to the MainApp variable passed in, instead of the correct way, setting the instance variable to the reference that is passed in.

So you have MainApp1 -> creates ExampleHelper -> creates MainApp2.  The cheeseClicks are incrementing and decrementing the counter on the original MainApp instance, but in the helper app, you are printing the counter from the new, not displayed MainApp instance.

Don't try to create a new MainApp instance, and assign the variable correctly, and you should get the results you want.

In `Form2`:

```
MainApp app = null;
public ExampleHelper(MainApp app1)
{
    app = app1; // note the change in order on this line...
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ExampleHelper_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved it with @Aaron's help. I deleted the 'app = new MainApp();' line. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you understand why it wasn't working?  You were basically creating another copy and then referencing that new copy, instead of maintaining a reference to the actual form where the click events were happening.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. I'm new to this references and multiple forms in the same project. Thanks